# Javascript: algorithm to convert Binary search tree to doubly linked list

Tags: javascript, algorithm, linked-list, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write the algorithm to convert a BST to a doubly linked list. This is what I have so far. Below is the code:

```js
function TreeNode(val) {
     this.val = val;
     this.left = this.right = null;
}

function BinaryTree() {
    this.root = null;
}
 
BinaryTree.prototype.push = function(val) {
    var root = this.root;
    
    if(!root) {
        this.root = new TreeNode(val);
        return;
    }
    
    var currentNode = root;
    var newNode = new TreeNode(val);
    
    while(currentNode) {
        if (val < currentNode.val) {
         if(!currentNode.left) {
            currentNode.left = newNode;
            break;
          } else {
              currentNode = currentNode.left;
          }
        } else if(val > currentNode.val) {
         if(!currentNode.right) {
            currentNode.right = newNode;
            break;
          } else {
              currentNode = currentNode.right;
          }
        }
    }
}
var bt = new BinaryTree();
bt.push(4);
bt.push(2);
bt.push(5);
bt.push(1);
bt.push(3);
//console.log(bt);
//var node = bt.root;
function Node(node) {
  //this.data = value;
  //this.previous = this.next = null;
  var head = null;
  var tail = null;
  var prev = null;
  console.log(bstToLL(node, head, prev, tail));
}


//function DoublyLinkedList() {
//  this.head = null;
//  this.prev = null;
//  this.tail = null;
//}

function bstToLL(node, head, prev, tail) {
 if (node === null) {
   return;
  }
  
  bstToLL(node.left, head, prev, tail);
  if (head === null) {
   head = node;
    //console.log(head)
  }
  if (prev === null) {
   prev = node;
    //console.log(prev)
  } else {
   //console.log(node);
    //console.log(prev);
    node.left = prev;
    prev.right = node;
  }
  prev = node
  bstToLL(node.right, head, prev, tail);
  if(node.right === null) {
   tail = node;
  }
  return head;
}

Node(bt.root);
```

The code works, but I don't think it is getting the right result. The binary tree looks like-

```
    4
   / \
  2   5
 / \
1   3
```

When I return the head from the bstToLL() method, I get an object with val 4 pointing to right child 5 and left child 2 and so on and so forth.

If you run the code, and check the debugger you will see the head object.

Can someone please guide me if I am doing this the right way, and how to fix the result?

Comment: Please include all the relevant code in the question itself. The link is not guaranteed to still work in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code which converts a binary tree into a `LinkedList`. It will log `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, and `5`, in order:

```
function TreeNode(left, value, right) {
  this.left = left;
  this.value = value;
  this.right = right;
}

function ListNode(prev, value, next) {
  this.prev = prev;
  this.value = value;
  this.next = next;
}

function LinkedList(head, tail) {
  if (tail === undefined) tail = head;
  this.head = head;
  this.tail = tail;
}
LinkedList.prototype.addToStart = function(list) {
  this.head.prev = list.tail;
  list.tail.next = this.head;
  this.head = list.head;
}
LinkedList.prototype.addToEnd = function(list) {
  this.tail.next = list.head;
  list.head.prev = this.tail;
  this.tail = list.tail;
};

function bstToLL(tree) {
  var centerNode = new ListNode(null, tree.value, null);
  var list = new LinkedList(centerNode);
  if (tree.left) list.addToStart(bstToLL(tree.left));
  if (tree.right) list.addToEnd(bstToLL(tree.right));
  return list;
}

var tree = new TreeNode(
  new TreeNode(
    new TreeNode(null, 1, null),
    2,
    new TreeNode(null, 3, null)
  ),
  4,
  new TreeNode(null, 5, null)
);
var linkedList = bstToLL(tree);
for (var node = linkedList.head; node; node = node.next) console.log(node.value);
```